# Access-Control-Allow-Origin with Ajax + PHP

Tags: php, ajax, cors

I have a problem which I cannot solve, even though there are a couple of questions like this already asked. None of the answers however helped me here:

I have a simple request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: webServiceUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d.StatusMessage);
    });
```

As from my error-message, I get the following error-message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.my-site.com/myFile.php' from origin 'http://another-server.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I read a bit about it and tried several approaches like changing the dataType to `jsonp`, add the param `crossDomain: true` as well as adding the specific header, but the error still remains. On my end of the server, I see that the request is being recognized, but I don't have any values or the payload.

My PHP-File looks like this:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$arr = array ('item1'=>"test1",'item2'=>"test2",'item3'=>"test3");      
$test = json_encode($arr);
echo $test;
```

When I'm using `jsonp` instead of `json` in the datatype, I even get a http-code `200`, but another notice rises and I'm still missing the data:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://my-site.com/

Anything else what I can try?

This is how my logged requests look like:

```
HTTP_HOST = www.my-site.com
HTTP_CONNECTION = close
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = de,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.7
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = gzip, deflate, br
HTTP_USER_AGENT = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36
HTTP_REFERER = http://another-site.net
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST = empty
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE = cross-site
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE = cors
HTTP_ORIGIN = http://another-site.net
HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS = content-type
HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD = POST
HTTP_ACCEPT = */*
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL = no-cache
HTTP_PRAGMA = no-cache
```

Comment: `headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://my-site.com' }`  — `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header. It has **no business** being on the request.

Comment: `crossDomain: true` has no effect unless you are making a **same origin** request that gets redirected to be cross origin. Leave that out.

Comment: `data: "{'qvDataTable':" + JSON.stringify(obj) + "}",` — You are generating invalid JSON. Don't generate JSON by mashing string together. Just make your object and pass *the whole thing* through `JSON.stringify`

Comment: "When I'm using jsonp instead of json in the datatype" — JSONP is (a) incompatible with responses that are not formatted as JSON and (b) incompatible with making POST requests

Comment: Given `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` I would **expect** the preflight options response to include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. You should do some debugging. Add logging statements to the PHP to make sure the right script is being triggered. Use the Network tab in the browser's developer tools to look at the request being made and the response you get.

Comment: You said `dataType: "json",` but the PHP is returning HTML. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Quentin I got rid of the headers + cross-domain in my JS-file. I also adjusted the JSON-thing for test-purposes and switched back to dataType `json`. I get an output though, have a look at the updated question

Comment: Please also update the code of the request. Have your PHP echo a simple JSON string for a start, as you are requesting JSON.

Comment: So the origin of the request is HTTP and the PHP endpoint is HTTPS, not the other way around. Do you confirm?

Comment: Yes. this is correct. I think with your tips I'm getting there. I think I have to allow specific headers in my PHP script as well. I'll give that a shot real quick

Comment: Doesn't matter whether the request is HTTP or HTTPS. Check out the attached screenshot in the answers sections

Comment: I have updated my answer just give it a try.

Comment: Your issue resolved? @DasSaffe

Comment: Yes, it is solved @RahulKathet. I had to add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');` to my PHP file. Thank you for your help everyone

Answer (score -1):

Updating my answer based on @DasSaffe response adding his solution here:

The answer is in the error response **content-type**

```
Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

---

We also have to add below code in our php file, if our error response says "**Content-type**" is not allowed

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
```

---

I have created 2 servers using ngrok and done the same thing as you described.

I have removed below and it did worked

```
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // REMOVE THIS
```

And when I add this back it gives me error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cfd2365835e8.ngrok.io/research/issueresolver/test.php' from origin 'http://3f6f1317ffc6.in.ngrok.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

[image]

[image]

And I am assuming your PHP has header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

Just give it a try and change the code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "YOUR PATH",
        data: {}, 
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // REMOVE THIS
        dataType: "json", KEEP IT LIKE THIS
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg)
            //alert(msg.d.StatusMessage);
        }
    })
```

---

Screenshot attached

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]